# How to manipulate the query paths of each endpoint, with RTK Query APIs generated from codegen-openapi?

Tags: swagger, openapi, redux-toolkit, openapi-generator, rtk-query

In our app, we want to use Redux Toolkit Query, and also auto generate the API definitions based on the swagger definitions from the backend.

Our backend consists of several micro services which each have their own swagger documentation and are located at different paths on the API server. Example:

- https://api.companyname.com/serviceA/endpoint1
- https://api.companyname.com/serviceA/endpoint2
- https://api.companyname.com/serviceB/endpoint1

However, when we generate the API integrations, the URLs are like `endpoint1`, `endpoint2` etc and does not contain the `serviceA` URL which is the path of the microservice itself.

For now, the only way to make things work, are manually doing changes like this:

Change from

```
    indexOfYear: build.query<IndexOfYearApiResponse, IndexOfYearApiArg>({
      query: queryArg => ({url: `/year/${queryArg.year}`}),
    }),
```

into

```
    indexOfYear: build.query<IndexOfYearApiResponse, IndexOfYearApiArg>({
      query: queryArg => ({url: `/taxes/year/${queryArg.year}`}),
    }),
```

I've been looking at the options mentioned here, but can't seem to find any way to add some URL prefix to the auto generated API integrations, but maybe someone else have an idea how it can be done?

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/code-generation

Answer (score -1):

You can set the baseURL in your emptyApi file like this

```
export const emptySplitApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/taxes' }),
  endpoints: () => ({}),
})
```

This will make sure all the api urls have a prefix of /year before them

Comment: My `emptySplitApi` is shared between features. 

When RTK generates a new API, it adds endpoints to it. So changing the base URL does not help much.